# Feu orange ou feu jaune ?

Tags: choix-de-mot, oral

Les trois états d'un [feu de circulation](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feu_de_circulation):

- feu vert,
- feu xxxxx,
- feu rouge.

J'ai toujours entendu parler de feu orange, mais l'article Wikipédia ne contient même pas le mot « orange ». L'article contient cependant « jaune-orangé », qui n'est probablement utilisé par personne dans la vie réelle. Dans certaines conditions Orange semble [gagner](http://www.googlefight.com/%22passe+a+l'orange%22-vs-%22passe+au+jaune%22.php) sur Google Fight, même si ça ne veut pas forcément dire grand chose.

**QUESTION:** Dans la vie courante, les francophones disent-ils « feu orange » ou « feu jaune » ? Si ça dépend des pays/régions je veux bien le détail.
Bonus: Les lois utilisent-elles un mot différent ?

Comment: J'ai toujours entendu parler de **feu orange** (Est de la France) et jamais de feu jaune. Les forces de l'ordre peuvent d'ailleurs vous arrêter s'ils estiment que vous n'êtes pas « passé **à l'orange** » mais au rouge.

Comment: Dans le sud de la France, feu orange aussi. Et je crois bien que pour passer son permis, toutes les questions parlent de feu orange (je n'ai jamais entendu parler de feu jaune...), et c'est national.

Comment: Pareil pour le Sud-Ouest.

Comment: Officiellement jaune, et orange dans la vie de tous les jours.

Comment: +1 Interesting question! Not that it matters, but here in the US most legal authorities/codes officially call it “amber”, whereas most drivers call it “yellow” (I think in Britain most drivers call it “amber.”). Personally, I call it “yellow” and associate it with “caution” (although many drivers here in Virginia drive as if they associate it with “gun it”), just as I associate **yellow** (not amber) flags at the beach and **yellow** (not amber) cards and flags on sports fields and race tracks with caution.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Vivant dans le Nord-Est de la France je n'ai jamais entendu un particulier utiliser "feu jaune". Par contre "feu orange" est couramment employé. On parle même d'"orange mûr" quand on passe au moment où le feu change de orange à rouge.

Il semblerait cependant que les textes de lois utilisent feu jaune :

> Les feux lumineux réglementant la circulation des véhicules ou la
>   traversée des piétons sont verts, jaunes ou rouges, le jaune et le
>   rouge pouvant être clignotants ; ils peuvent être blancs lorsqu'ils ne
>   concernent que les véhicules des services réguliers de transport en
>   commun.

source: http://www.legifrance.gouv.fr/affichTexteArticle.do?idArticle=LEGIARTI000018359507&cidTexte=JORFTEXT000000829916&dateTexte=

Comment: Je confirme pour l'emploi du quotidien, en Belgique on parle aussi de feu "orange".

Comment: En pratique en France la couleur du feu est tire plus sur l'orange que le jaune, le [code de la route parle de feu orange / jaune](http://www.passetoncode.fr/cours/feux-tricolores/). La [sécurité routière aussi](http://www.legipermis.com/infractions/non-respect-feu-orange.html).  C'est un cas où les textes de loi qui se font à coups de modifications par reprises n'ont pas intégré les évolutions techniques.

Answer (score 7):

Au Québec, si on en croit la législation<sup>1</sup>, c'est *jaune* pour le feu traditionnel, et *orange* pour la main clignotante :

> 361 . À moins d'une signalisation contraire, face à un feu **jaune**, le
>   conducteur d'un véhicule routier ou d'une bicyclette doit immobiliser
>   son véhicule avant le passage pour piétons ou la ligne d'arrêt ou,
>   s'il n'y en a pas, avant la ligne latérale de la chaussée qu'il
>   s'apprête à croiser, à moins qu'il n'y soit engagé ou en soit si près
>   qu'il lui serait impossible d'immobiliser son véhicule sans danger. Il
>   ne peut poursuivre sa route que lorsqu'un signal lui permettant
>   d'avancer apparaît.
>
> 444 . [...] En face d'une main **orange** fixe, un piéton ne peut
>   s'engager sur la chaussée. [...]
>
> [ [*Code de la sécurité routière*](http://legisquebec.gouv.qc.ca/fr/ShowDoc/cs/C-24.2), L.R.Q., c. C-24.2 ]

Je n'y ai jamais entendu autre chose que « *le feu/la lumière est jaune !* ».

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> Certaines autres provinces (Canada)... [Manitoba](http://web2.gov.mb.ca/laws/statutes/ccsm/h060f.php#88%285%29) : « *jaune ou orangé* » ; [Ontario](http://www.ontario.ca/fr/lois/loi/90h08?search=code%20route#BK232) :  « *jaune* » ; [Nouveau-Brunswick](http://laws.gnb.ca/fr/showfulldoc/cs/M-17//20150924) : « *jaune ou jaune-orange* ».</sub>

Comment: Par comparaison de cette réponse et de l'article Wikipédia cité en question, j'ai le sentiment que celui-ci a été rédigé en grande partie par un québécois. :) Merci pour les informations comme toujours recherchées et complètes.

Comment: La couleur du feu de circulation au Québec est définitivement plus jaunâtre que la couleur de la main pour piétons, qui est même parfois presque rouge!

Answer (score 4):

Le feu intermédiaire est bien orange à l'œil , mais le code de la route français le décrit sans équivoque comme "le feu jaune" . 
c.f. : http://www.legifrance.gouv.fr/affichTexteArticle.do?idArticle=LEGIARTI000018359507&cidTexte=JORFTEXT000000829916&dateTexte=

Comment: [Lien](http://legifrance.gouv.fr/affichCode.do;jsessionid=0593529DDA076472900300F320BF48A2.tpdila19v_2?idSectionTA=LEGISCTA000006177124&cidTexte=LEGITEXT000006074228&dateTexte=20150925). Merci.

Comment: Ceci était déjà mentionné dans [la réponse de Binary Override](http://french.stackexchange.com/a/16080/7224).

Answer (score 0):

Bien que j'entends souvent les termes feu rouge et feu vert, il me semble bizarre de parler de "feu orange".

Généralement on se contentera de dire que "le feu passe à l'orange".

---

Cette réponse est *personnelle*.

Bien qu'étant Belge, je ne peux certifier si ma réponse s'applique à quiconque d'autre que mon entourage et moi: c'est fort probable mais j'en ignore la portée actuelle, soit-elle partagée par tous les francophones, juste en Belgique ou même pas.

Comment: Pourquoi te semble-t-il bizarre de parler de « feu orange » alors que  « feu vert » et « feu rouge » ne te choquent pas ?

Comment: @jlliagre Il s'agit tout d'abord d'un ressentit en tant que natif mais la cause vient peut-être du fait que le feu orange est plus transitif/temporaire que les deux autres qui eux sont deux états "clairs et nets".

Comment: Quoi qu'il en soit la question est de savoir si, quand on parle de cette position intermédiaire, on parle de la couleur jaune ou de l'orange...

Comment: @Laurents J'ai toujours entendu et dit orange et non jaune.

Comment: Le feu orange peut être "permanent" et pas seulement transitoire entre vert et rouge, mais dans ce cas, il doit clignoter. Pour ce qui est du nommage de la couleur, je confirme qu'en France, on dit toujours orange et jamais jaune. Les textes de lois préfèrent cette dernière couleur pour une raison que j'ignore.